# Invalid column name (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have method on back end to add data to table. I am using a database-first approach.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] 
(
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Comment_text] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Id_external]  INT            NULL,
    [Author]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Comments_ToTable] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Id_external]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Interwiers] ([Interwier_id])
);
```

Here is the model class for this table:

```
public partial class Comment
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Comment_text { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Id_external { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }

        public virtual Interwier Interwier { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Interwier class:

```
public partial class Interwier
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

        public Interwier()
        {
            this.Links = new HashSet<Link>();
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Interwier_id { get; set; }
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public int Birthday { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Salary { get; set; }
        public string English { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Interview_Id { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Current_work { get; set; }
        public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday; } }
        public virtual Interview Interview { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is method, how I try to add data

```
public ActionResult AddComment(string name,string commentText, string interwierName)
{
    var Id = db.InterwierModels
            .Where(x => x.FIO == interwierName)
            .Select(x => x.Interwier_id
            ).FirstOrDefault();

    //var idForCreating = Int32.Parse(Id.ToString());

    Comment cmnt = new Comment()
        {
            Author = name,
            Comment_text = commentText,
            Id_external = Id
        };

    db.Comments.Add(cmnt);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
}
```

When I add, I get this error

> Invalid column name 'Interwier_Interwier_id'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column
>   name 'Interwier_Interwier_id'.

I try to find `Interwier_Interwier_id` in solution, but I didn't find it.

Rebuild and clean also not works.

Where can the problem be, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not related, but the Attribute DataType.Date on an int property doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Please don't put database layer code in the controller layer.

Comment: Anyway, where is may be problem with column?@Neil

Comment: Have you tried using `[ForeignKey("Interwier_id")]` to mark this virtual property: `public virtual Interwier Interwier { get; set; }`? You've relationship mapping problem for Comment & Interwier tables.

Comment: `Interwier` probably should be `Interviewer` .....

Comment: Try this: int? Id = db.InterwierModels
            .Where(x => x.FIO == interwierName)
            .Select(x =>(int?) x.Interwier_id
            ).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: You mean in Comments class? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: How it related to my problem?@Tomato32

Comment: @mark_spencer Yes, the virtual property only exist in `Comment` class. Seems EF tried to find out foreign key relationship between those tables but don't find anything.

Comment: I have error after adding `The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Interwier' on type 'SmartSolutions.Models.Comment' is not valid. The foreign key name 'Interwier_id' was not found on the dependent type 'SmartSolutions.Models.Comment'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.` @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: I solved problem, need to add
`[ForeignKey("Id_external")]`@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Thank you for help!@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: @mark_spencer I'm also unaware that you're need `Id_external` besides suggested FK too. Glad that your problem is now solved.